# Proof of problem 6 G. Bartle "Introduction to real analysis"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I need a help. Can somebody check,do I understand correctly a proof of next exercise.

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an interval and $f:I \to \mathbb R$ be increasing function on $I$. Suppose $c \in I$ is not an endpoint of $I$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $I$ such that $(x_n)<c$ for $n=1,3,5...$ and $(x_n)>c$ for $n=2,4,6$; and such that $c=\lim(x_n)$ and $f(c)=\lim f(x_n))$.

$j_f(c)$ is jump of $f$ at point $c$.

$\textbf{Proof in the book}$:

$"\Rightarrow"$ is trivial.

$"\Leftarrow"$

Since $0\leq j_f(c)\leq f(x_{2n})-f(x_{2n+1})$ $\textbf{it follows that $j_f(c)=0$}$. So $f$ is continuous at $c$. The question is, why does it follow?

$\textbf{My assumption}$: I think, here was used the Squeeze Theorem. If $0\leq j_f(c) \leq f(x_{2n})-f(x_{2n+1})$ then it has to be $0\leq j_f(c) \leq 0$. Now the question is, why is it $f(x_{2n})-f(x_{2n+1})=0$. I think because $(x_n)$ converges to $c$ and thus every subsequence converges to $c$ so  $f(x_{2n})-f(x_{2n+1})=f(c)-f(c)=0$. Am I right? Can somebody explain me this,please. Thank you for help!

Comment: Your justification for the "it follows that $j_f(c)=0$" claim looks good. Make sure you understand also why the inequality $j_f(c) \le f(x_{2n}) - f(x_{2n+1})$ is true.

Comment: @angryavian thank you for your answer)) It is a problem, because I don't understand, why it's true).  Maybe I understand it right, but I'm not sure.Why is $f(x_{2n}) \leq f(x_{2n+1})$?. I understand why this inequality is true.(  Because $(x_{2n+1}) \leq (x_{2n})$ then $f(x_{2n}) \leq f(x_{2n+1})$ because $f$ is increasing). But it has to be equal zero, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is $j_f(c) \le f(x_{2n}) - f(x_{2n+1})$ true?

Since $f$ is increasing and $x_{2n+1} < c < x_{2n}$ we have
$$f(x_{2n+1}) \le \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) \le f(x_{2n})$$
and thus
$$j_f(c) := \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) - \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) \le f(x_{2n}) - f(x_{2n+1}).$$

---

> Why is $f(x_{2n}) \le f(x_{2n+1})$?

It is not true that $f(x_{2n}) \le f(x_{2n+1})$ for a given $n$. But it is true in the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Since $0 \le j_f(c) \le f(x_{2n}) - f(x_{2n+1})$ holds for each $n$, we can take the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the right-hand side to get $0 \le j_f(c) \le 0$ as you mentioned in your post.